# Same position of texts created by geom_text_repel() in several maps created from a loop

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I have a loop that creates prediction maps for the months of the year. I create this using the R language, with the ggplot2 library and in it I include the geom_text_repel() function, which does not allow the labels of the points that are contained not to overlap. The problem is that after each iteration, the labels of the points for each map have different positions, so when creating a presentation of the maps, the change of position of these labels is more noticeable than the variability of the prediction as such and it turns out to be unfavorable. How do I make that after the first iteration of the loop, the positions that geom_text_repel() gives to each label are maintained for the following iterations? This is the fragment of my loop in which I use such a function:

```
#...Previous code...
geom_point(data=ubic, 
           aes(x=X,y=Y), 
           shape=24,
           size=0.6,
           fill="#006400",
           color="#006400") +
geom_text_repel(data=ubic,
                aes(x=X,y=Y,label=Estation),
                color="#006400",
                size=3) + 
#...Subsequent code...
```

These are examples of maps created for two months of the year:

[Month 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pqml.png)
[Month 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFnjc.png)

Answer (score 1):

Placing labels with `geom_text_repel` entails a random element, i.e. even if the original coordinates are the same, the positions chosen by `geom_text_repel` will in general differ. For that reason and for reproducibilty `geom_text_repel` has a `seed=` argument.

Note: A second option would be to make one run using `geom_text_repel` to get the positions for the labels which can be extracted using e.g. `ggplot2::layer_data()`. Then use these positions in a `geom_text` for subsequent maps.

Using a minimal reproducible example based on the default example from `?geom_sf`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(patchwork)

nc <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE)

dat_point <- data.frame(
  x = -c(80, 78),
  y = c(35, 36),
  label = c("Foo", "Bar")
)

base <- ggplot(nc) +
  geom_sf(fill = "grey95") +
  geom_point(data = dat_point, aes(x, y), colour = "red", size = 1) +
  theme_void()

p_seed <- lapply(1:2, \(x) base +
  geom_text_repel(
    data = dat_point, aes(x, y, label = label),
    colour = "red", size = 6
  ))

wrap_plots(p_seed, ncol = 1) +
  plot_annotation(
    title = "Without the seed set",
    subtitle = "... the labels are placed at different positions"
  )
```

[image]

```r
p_seed <- lapply(1:2, \(x) base +
  geom_text_repel(
    data = dat_point, aes(x, y, label = label),
    colour = "red", size = 6,
    seed = 123
  ))

wrap_plots(p_seed, ncol = 1) +
  plot_annotation(
    title = "With seed set",
    subtitle = "... the labels are placed at identical positions"
  )
```

[image]